# Pipe multiple commands in find --exec

Tags: shell, find

In the shell I want to list the line counts of every file matching a specific filename pattern. My approach is to use `find` to select the files, use `-exec cat {}` to print them out and use `|wc -l` to count the lines.

```
find . -type f -name 'priceupdate*csv' -print0 -exec cat {} \;
```

does print all the content, but

```
find . -type f -name 'priceupdate*csv' -print0 -exec cat {}|wc -l \;
```

alerts

```
wc: ';'find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want the line count of the complete content of all the cat-ed files at once (or) individually

Comment: Exercise for the reader: explain why `find . -type f -exec wc -l < {} \;` doesn't work to count the lines of each file in (and below) the current directory.

Comment: How about `wc -l priceupdate*.csv` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell That'll show line count per file as opposed to total line count.

Comment: ...which might be the intention, after re-reading the question. Not 100% clear to me.

Comment: Or `wc -l < priceupdate*.csv` if you want them aggregated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` runs a single command with its arguments, not an arbitrary shell command. To do that, you need to explicitly run a shell.

```
find . -type f -name 'priceupdate*csv' -print0 -exec sh -c  'cat "$1" |wc -l' _ {} \;
```

As a general rule, it is better to pass the expansion of `{}` as an argument rather than try to incorporate it directly into the command, to avoid surprises due to shell parsing.

(I'm limiting this answer to the question as asked, rather than getting into the various issues with the actual shell command involved.)

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain the underscore at the end?

Comment: It's a dummy argument. The first positional argument following the string to execute is used to set `$0` in that shell, but you rarely care what its value is. `{}`, then, is used to set `$1` inside the shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -name 'priceupdate*csv' -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

Or you can just do:

```
find . -type f -name 'priceupdate*csv' -exec wc -l {} +
```